# What can I say when someone has dialed the wrong number?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Let's say I get a wrong number and I want to politely tell them that it is the wrong number. To do that, can I say/ask

> What number are you **trying**?
>
> Who do you **want to speak to**?

Comment: As for your second question, another way to say it is, "Who are you trying to reach?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both the answers you suggest are polite, and don't divulge your identity in the process.
I'd probably phrase the first as

> What number are you trying to reach?

If the person on the other end doesn't realize at once that they've reached a wrong number, I'd follow their answer with

> I believe you've reached a wrong number.

and that usually finishes it.

Comment: Often, a caller will ask for a specific person: "May I speak to John Doe?" You can say, "I'm sorry, there is no one by that name here. I think you've got the wrong number." This doesn't tell the caller much about your identity, either. It just tells them you are not who they were trying to call.

Answer (score 15):

A simple

> Sorry, I think you have the wrong number.

suffices. They will probably apologize and say bye. It does not need to be any more complicated than that.

Comment: I agree with this because "the wrong number" is used for a specific example of a wrong number.